# Why did Angular stop working locally all of a sudden?

Tags: angularjs

I'm experimenting with a very basic Angular page locally.  I'm able to accomplish this on my Windows pc by running http-server.  However, this stopped working today.  I've gone back and reduced my pages to extremely-basic, hello-world-level code, but I still can't get any Angular functionality to work.

Does anyone know why the following page wouldn't output a basic math problem, instead of curly brackets?  As I mentioned, this worked fine yesterday.

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('store', []);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <p>{{"Hello" + " you"}}, I am {{2017 - 1985}}.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
The error I see in Chrome DevTools is as follows (currently using AngularJS v1.6.1 ):

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=store&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.1%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)
at angular.js:38
at angular.js:4759
at q (angular.js:357)
at g (angular.js:4720)
at eb (angular.js:4642)
at c (angular.js:1838)
at Mc (angular.js:1859)
at pe (angular.js:1744)
at angular.js:32977
at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3314)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:38
(anonymous) @ angular.js:4759
q @ angular.js:357
g @ angular.js:4720
eb @ angular.js:4642
c @ angular.js:1838
Mc @ angular.js:1859
pe @ angular.js:1744
(anonymous) @ angular.js:32977
b @ angular.js:3314
```

Comment: What happens if you change the angular version? This one is working for me, https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js

Comment: If it's not interpolating the curly braces, you should have a browser error. What's the browser error?

Comment: @BenBeck - I've added the browser error.  Thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: @WEFX, I would try the answer below. The error you're getting is very generic. It's probably your script ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call Angular before you call app.js for one. JavaScript executes in sequential order.

Comment: I assume that they would also want app.js to be at the end of the body so that the body/module/whatever has loaded before trying to be used.